# AMP Page Analytics Component Multiple buttonClick Trigger Events

Tags: html, json, amp-html

If you see the code below written in an Accelerated Mobile Page (AMP) component. It works great.

When a button with the CSS selector ".fbATC" is clicked, then the FB pixel custom event is fired.

```
<amp-analytics type="facebookpixel" id="facebook-pixel">
        <script type="application/json">
        {
          "vars": {
             "pixelId": "ID"
          },
          "triggers": {
            "defaultPageview": {
              "on": "visible",
              "request": "pageview"
            },
            "trackPageview": {
              "on": "visible",
              "request": "event",
              "vars": {
                "eventName": "customVC",
                "content_name": "QUERY_PARAM(utm_campaign)-QUERY_PARAM(utm_source)"
              }
            },
            "buttonClick": {
            "selector":".fbATC",
              "on": "click",
              "request": "event",
              "vars": {
                "eventName": "customATC",
                "content_name": "QUERY_PARAM(utm_campaign)-QUERY_PARAM(utm_source)"
              }
            }
          }
        }
        </script>
        </amp-analytics>
```

However, I want to add another `buttonClick` event.

When I try to do this:

```
<amp-analytics type="facebookpixel" id="facebook-pixel">
<script type="application/json">
{
  "vars": {
     "pixelId": "ID"
  },
  "triggers": {
    "defaultPageview": {
      "on": "visible",
      "request": "pageview"
    },
    "trackPageview": {
      "on": "visible",
      "request": "event",
      "vars": {
        "eventName": "customVC",
        "content_name": "QUERY_PARAM(utm_campaign)-QUERY_PARAM(utm_source)"
      }
    },
    "buttonClick": {
    "selector":".fbATC",
      "on": "click",
      "request": "event",
      "vars": {
        "eventName": "customATC",
        "content_name": "QUERY_PARAM(utm_campaign)-QUERY_PARAM(utm_source)",
      }
    },
    "buttonClick": {
    "selector":".anotherClass",
      "on": "click",
      "request": "event",
      "vars": {
        "eventName": "customATC",
        "content_name": "QUERY_PARAM(utm_campaign)-QUERY_PARAM(utm_source)"
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
</amp-analytics>
```

Then the last `buttonClick` with the CSS selector ".anotherClass" works. However, the one above it doesn't.

It's like its overwriting the one above it.

I thought by adding another key/value pair, it would add this extra `buttonClick` event.

Googling around I can't really find anything. Other than this article:

https://help.instapage.com/hc/en-us/articles/360025465573-Facebook-Pixel-conversion-tracking-for-AMP

Appears I'm doing everything right.

Can someone please help me. What am I doing wrong? Is my JSON structured correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yayyyy! Problem solved!**

I've discovered that the button click names need to be unique.

So I must have `buttonClick`, then `buttonClick2`, `buttonClick3`...

AMP recognizes and makes sense of these.

This makes total sense. Explains the behaviour of the last event appearing to overwrite the previous ones.

Comment: why don't you add multiple selectors like this for the same event `"selector": ".fbATC, .anotherClass"`

Comment: How about to track scroll depth instead of button click?